# Groovy: trouble printing out attributes from xml

Tags: groovy

I am trying to parse a xml file and print out attributes but it is not working.

Here is the Groovy code:

```
def Server1 = new XmlParser().parse('c:\\temp\\webSimplified.xml')
Server1.each {
    println "Stuff in session-config: ${it}"
    it.attributes().each {
        println 'PLEASE PRINT OUT ATTRIBUTES: '
        println it.toString()
    }
}
```

Here is the webSimplified.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>fork</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

And here is the results from running my Groovy script: Nothing prints out from the 'it.attributes().each {'  segment.  How can I get that to work?

```
Stuff in session-config: {http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee}servlet[attributes={}; value=[{http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee}servlet-name[attributes={}; value=[jsp]], {http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee}servlet-class[attributes={}; value=[org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet]], {http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee}init-param[attributes={}; value=[{http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee}param-name[attributes={}; value=[fork]], {http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee}param-value[attributes={}; value=[false]]]], {http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee}init-param[attributes={}; value=[{http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee}param-name[attributes={}; value=[xpoweredBy]], {http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee}param-value[attributes={}; value=[false]]]], {http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee}load-on-startup[attributes={}; value=[3]]]]
Stuff in session-config: {http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee}session-config[attributes={}; value=[{http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee}session-timeout[attributes={}; value=[30]]]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Which attributes are you trying to print? The ones in `<web-app>` or scan the xml and print all of the attributes for all of the nodes?

Comment: There is no attribute in the "session-config" element if you want to output that. Are you trying to get "session-timeout" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course nothing is printed. I taught you in the other answer how to print out attributes, butt you have no attributes, but child tags.

Try this:

```
def Server1 = new XmlParser().parse(/c:\temp\webSimplified.xml/)
Server1.each {
    println "Stuff in ${it.name().localPart}: $it"
    println()
    it.children().each {
        println 'PLEASE PRINT OUT child element: '
        println it
        println()
    }
    3.times { println() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
def Server1 = new XmlParser().parseText('''

<web-app 
  version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>fork</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>

''')
```

Output:

```
servlet-name : jsp
servlet-class : org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
init-param : 
init-param : 
load-on-startup : 3
session-timeout : 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to print the sesssion config values (a qualified guess based on your question), the following would work:

```
def str = '''
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>fork</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
'''

def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(str)
xml.'session-config'.'*'.each { node -> 
  println "${node.name().localPart} -> ${node.text()}"
}
```

note that node is an instance of [groovy.util.Node](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Node.html) and node.name() returns an instance of [QName](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/xml/QName.html) which is a namespace aware object. To get the 'local name' we call 'localPart' on the QName.

The gpath expression `xml.'session-config'.'*'.each` means:

from the root node (i.e. the xml variable here), select all child nodes with the name 'session-config' and then iterate over all child nodes under that node.

The above prints:

```
session-timeout -> 30
```